# ADFv2: How to remove connection to GIT repository once set up?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Currently, ADFv2 allows you to set up Code Repository and automatically synchronise JSON files of components of pipelines, datasets, etc with repo (e.g.GIT).
But, once you set it up - how to actually remove it or change configuration (not branch)?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In overview tab, there is a repository settings button, click it, you will see the remove repository button. [image]

Comment: Thanks @fang-liu. 
I have posted more details about adding/removing a repository from ADF here: [Setting up Code Repository for Azure Data Factory v2](https://sqlplayer.net/2018/10/setting-up-code-repository-for-azure-data-factory-v2/)